# Adding items dynamically from javascript array in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have this code

```
    var filter = {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Choose',
            items: [
               // I need to put checkboxes here
            ]
        }]
    };
```

I need to dynamically add checkbox items:

```
{
   xtype: 'checkboxfield',
   name: 'city[]',
   label: 'City name',
   checked: false,
}
```

The data that I need to add is stored in JS array, and checkbox can be checked or unchecked

Please help,
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your issue? When do you add? What is the event?

```
filter.items[0].items[filter.items[0].items.length] = {
   xtype: 'checkboxfield',
   name: 'city[]',
   label: 'City name',
   checked: false,
}
```

or

```
var checkbox = {
       xtype: 'checkboxfield',
       name: 'city[]',
       label: 'City name',
       checked: false,
    }
var itemArr = filter.items[0].items;
itemArr[itemArr.length]=checkbox;
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the first example.
How can I now know if some checkbox has been checked?

Comment: I do not do extjs, but perhaps checked=Ext.getCmp('city[]')

Answer (score -1):

What is `filter`, is it a `Container` or does it extend from it (Panel, FormPanel, etc.)?

If so, you can use the [`add()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.container.Container-method-add) method to dynamically add to it.

It's also good to note, that posting in the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/) will get your a much faster response.